# How to force html elements into one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have some elements like:

```
    <div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis"> 
Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
    <div style="float: right">Float text</div>
    </div>
```

This will display something like:

```
Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt...
                                       Float text
```

However I want it to be like:

```
Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt...Float text
```

I try to use the absolute position method, but in this way, the ellipsis will not be shown.

Is there any way I can do this?

NOTICE:

Not sure what's wrong, but many people suggest with the inline block or span way, both doesn't work. While putting the float text before 'Textttt' DOES work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the right-floated block BEFORE the text you want it to be in line with.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis">
  <div style="float: right">Float text</div>
  Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pkfwnan7/

Comment: This is amazing, it really works, though I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Update

For either of the below solution to have ellipsis on the left text, it needs a width set, either explicit or by running out of space and have `overflow: hidden`/`text-overflow: ellipsis`.

You do like this, where the outer div (`wrap`) has `white-space: nowrap` and the inner displays like inline block

```css
.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.wrap > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wrap > div:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div> 
    Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
    text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  <div>Float text</div>
</div>
```

Or with `display: table`

```css
.wrap {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
}
.wrap > * {
  display: table-cell;
}

.wrap > div:first-child div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div> 
    <div>Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</div>
  </div>
  <div>Float text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **display:inline-block** to make the div inline

```
  <div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis"> 
Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
    <div style="display:inline-block">Float text</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use span instead

```
<span>Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
<span>Float text</span>
```

Or set `display: inline-block;` on the div elements

Also make sure the parent element does not have fixed width. But this will not be an issue since your'e using `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 1):

Put the text in a span. No need to add to CSS.

```
<span>Text Here</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping everything inside a span class

```html
<span> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis">
    </div>
</span> 

<span>
    <div style="float: right;">Float text</div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted are somewhat right but you can even simplify your markup:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;"> 
   Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt Float text
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4z1pqkyj/1/)

> The white-space property is used to describe how whitespace inside the element is handled.
>
> > **nowrap**
> > Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

[MDN on white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: That won't do what OP wants, as the `Texttttt…` can't be shortened with an ellipsis while retaining `Float text` this way.

Answer (score 0):

Give both of the elements a display:inline-block property. You had several quotation marks and a closing div tag missing. All of this has been fixed and can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hLjsayh/1/).

The updated html is below:

```
<div>
   <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis;display:inline-block"> 
       Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
   </div>
   <div style="float: right;display:inline-block">
       Float text
   </div>
</div>
```